# If i write an HTTP server. will i be able to serve angular app?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, http, webserver

i am trying to create a custom HTTP web server for my Angular 4 Application in c#.

should i continue, or are there some things that i should know of?

thanks

**__UPDATE__**

i served my `Angular dist files` in `IIS7` some tweaks were required for it work properly. but i am working on an application that uses angular `dist files` as frontend. and i want a custom `http server` built in my application to serve the angular `dist files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can do this, it is not the ideal way to serve an angular application. The best approach would be to serve the static production build files via a CDN that that supports gzipping.

Comment: Using separate nginx server would be applicable as well.

Comment: i served my `Angular dist files` in `IIS7` some tweaks were required for it work properly. but i am working on an application that uses `angular dist files` as frontend. and i want a custom http server built in my application to serve the `angular dist files`

Comment: well i guess its gonna Work

Comment: well it did work. only the router module failed..
how can i fix it?

Comment: It could be to do with the routing strategy. Maybe try using hashLocationStratgey. Without examples I can't help more than that though. Try posting another question if you're still stuck